# flash player download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, flash

Canonical seems to have deleted flash player. Where can i download (from terminal or browser and install myself with sudo) for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

i uninstalled as some live sport site was not wwortking, then tried :

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Error I got :

> upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 413 not upgraded. Need
>   to get 8,958 kB of archives. After this operation, 31.1 MB of
>   additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Err http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty/partner adobe-flashplugin
>   i386 1:20170411.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150
>   80] Err http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty/partner
>   adobe-flash-properties-gtk i386 1:20170411.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   404 
>   Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80] E: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20170411.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_20170411.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-missing? t@t5:~$

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: oh i generally dont do that as its an old laptop.  i guess that is why...old links cached?

Comment: Yes, the version has been updated since last time you run that command.

Comment: Thank you. worked now. Though the website i wanted doe snot work still. guess wil try ububtu 16 like my other laptop. anyway should i delete this q?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why switching to a later Ubuntu version would make a difference in this respect. The 14.04 archive contains the latest version of both Firefox and Flash. Maybe you want to ask another question... But yes, it makes sense to delete this question.

Comment: I have 2 devices at home. one running Ubuntu 16 LTS (laptop more ram 4 core) and the other 14. both acer. 14 one has 2 GB Ram, a tablet... not sure what to do to make it work. will search more :_)

Comment: Using ubuntu 20.04 now. Flash working or not needed...:-)